# gf on partial with vim-rails not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim

My cursor is on * below:

```
  render partial:'payer*rows'
```

I hit gf and get the error E447 Can't find file "payer_row" in path.

What am I missing? The partial definitely exists...

Comment: It might be because, you haven't included its parent directory's path. Type :set path in command line and check whether the parent directory of payer_row is shown. If not, you can give :set path+=/FullPathUntilDirectoryName in .vimrc file. You can check in command line also.